# SQL Server : run a script on all databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL script with a function (function drops at the end of the script) and temporary table definitions and variables to process the data that gives me one single line result for a database.

It works but I need to run and get the all results for 1000 databases. It seems impossible to run the script seperately.

I have found `sp_MSForEachDB` single command line examples but I have a whole script and couldn't make it work with this way.

Is there any way to run a script on all the databases?

Thanks for reply

Comment: What does this script do exactly? You say it drops and creates function, but also temporary tables (so they aren't going to persist afterwards, which means this isn't a permanent thing). What is your actual goal? This might well be an xy question.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: the function and the temp tables are just used to process data and there is no problem with that.My actual goal is that i get a result from a database by running a single query script.But i have one thousand databases and i want to get all of the results together.

Comment: But what does that script tell you..? Clearly it's returning some kind of data, so, what is the work it is doing? I would hazard a guess that it can be achieved without creating temporary tables, and functions. Exactly like the link @hakeerMirza has given you tells you; instead of asking us how to complete your solution Y, tell us about your problem X.

Comment: As you were told already, try to provide more information about your actual goal. Is my assumption correct, that all these databases are living within different servers? Do you know, that you can trigger a script against all servers at once via "registered servers"? Please provide more background...

Comment: If this is not confidential or thousands of lines you might just provide your SQL code...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not saying this is a good idea, since we don't really know what this script you're running does, but this should work. I don't envy you the pain of getting all of the single quotes in the right places, but it's the price we pay for using undocumented, unsupported stored procedures.

```
DECLARE @sqlText varchar(max); 

SET @sqlText = 'IF ''?'' NOT IN(''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'') 
  BEGIN 
    USE ? 
    EXEC(''CREATE <functions, tables, what have you>'') 
  END';

EXECUTE sp_MSforeachdb @sqlText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi In SSMS you can run script for selected database with sqlcmd command.
here for example I want to run my script in two different database for it I have save my script in local. And calling it using **:r  "C:\temp\test1.sql"**.

Still I am thinking another way to do it using loop.

enable sql mode  SSMS > QUERY > SQLCMD Mode

```
use test
:r  "C:\temp\test1.sql"
use S2VTST6
:r  "C:\temp\test1.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to use a separate saved query file to run the script against a certain set of databases that were all under the same server. To do so, I read the contents of the sql file into a variable and then used the `sp_executesql` command to run it under each iteration of a cursor:

```
/*
    INSTRUCTIONS:
        * Save the sql file in a place that is accessible by the server
        * Change the path to match path of the directory!
        * Apply filters to the databases you are targeting
        (OPTIONAL) Try printing your command before executing it!
        (OPTIONAL) Inserting into a temp table requires you to define the same columns! (see below)
*/

CREATE TABLE #temp
    (Id INT, FOO DATETIME2(7), BAR VARCHAR(100))

/* !!! Change the file path !!! (must be accessible by the server) */
DECLARE @FileContents VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @FileContents = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\PathToYourFile\MyFile.sql', SINGLE_CLOB) x;

/* Instantiate a cursor to loop over each database */
DECLARE @DB_Name VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name 
FROM MASTER.sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4 AND state = 0 /*Online*/ AND
/* !!! apply a filter to target specific databases !!! */
    name LIKE '%ConsistentNamingConvention%'

/* Open and retrieve the first entry */
OPEN database_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    /* Use the database from the name on the cursor. Then run the command saved above */
    SELECT @Command = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DB_Name) + ';' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) --add 2 newlines
    + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    + @FileContents

    /* View the command (uncomment) */
    --PRINT @Command

    /* run the file contents against the specific database! */
    EXEC sp_executesql @Command 

    /* iterate the cursor to the next database name */
    FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END 
CLOSE database_cursor;
DEALLOCATE database_cursor;

SELECT * FROM #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

This assumes the MyFile.sql is using `INSERT INTO #Temp`! (`SELECT INTO` will not work)

Instructions:

1. Save the SQL file in a place accessible by the sql server
2. Change the path of the file to point to your file (line 16). Unfortunately this must be a string literal, not a variable
3. Filter what databases you are working with under the CURSOR declaration (line 26)

Again, this assumes that all of the databases you are interested in are on the same server.