# Run this script on all Databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below script that works fine & fetches all the results I need. However It does it only for the current DB context. I have several hundred databases in my instance and need to get the results for all databases in a single execution.
How do I modify the script to make it work for all Databases.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AllInfo', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #AllInfo;

CREATE TABLE #AllInfo (
dbase_name nvarchar(200),
tbl_name nvarchar(300),
column_name nvarchar(300),
min_date datetime
)
DECLARE @Statement varchar(2000);
DECLARE cr_MaxDateTime CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT 'SELECT DB_NAME(), ' + '''' + TAB.name + ''''  + ', ' + '''' + COL.name + '''' +' ,MIN([' + COL.name +']) AS ''Min' + COL.name + '_' + TAB.name + ''' FROM [' + SCH.name + '].[' + TAB.name + ']'
    FROM   sys.schemas AS SCH
    INNER  JOIN sys.tables AS TAB
           ON TAB.schema_id = SCH.schema_id
    INNER  JOIN sys.columns AS COL
           ON COL.object_id = TAB.object_id
    INNER  JOIN sys.types AS UDT
           ON COL.user_type_id = UDT.user_type_id
    INNER  JOIN sys.types AS TYP
           ON TYP.system_type_id = UDT.system_type_id AND
              TYP.user_type_id = TYP.system_type_id   AND
              TYP.name IN ('date', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'datetime', 'time')
    ORDER  BY SCH.name, TAB.name, COL.name
FOR READ ONLY;
OPEN cr_MaxDateTime;
FETCH cr_MaxDateTime INTO @Statement;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @Statement;
    INSERT INTO #AllInfo
    EXECUTE(@Statement);
    FETCH cr_MaxDateTime INTO @Statement;
END;
CLOSE cr_MaxDateTime;
DEALLOCATE cr_MaxDateTime;

select * from #AllInfo
```

I know sp_MSForEachDB may help, but the examples I could find are mostly single line commands. I couldn't make it work for the whole script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : run a script on all databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397798/sql-server-run-a-script-on-all-databases)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing SQL query on multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336171/executing-sql-query-on-multiple-databases)

Comment: Re: sp_msforeachdb, It's no different for a long script, just create a big long string with your whole thing and attach ?. to every table so it goes to correct database or add a USE ?. It's kind of a hassle though, since you usually have to replace a lot of quotes etc to make it work.

Comment: I did try sp_msforeachdb. As you can see, there are already quite a lot of quotes in the existing script. I just couldn't make it work after replacing all the quotes. It just giving me some or the other error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a modern and supported version of SQL Server, a simpler way to drop the #temp table (unnecessary of course if you put this code into a stored procedure):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AllInfo;

CREATE TABLE #AllInfo 
(
  dbase_name  nvarchar(130),
  tbl_name    nvarchar(260),
  column_name nvarchar(130),
  min_date    datetime
);
```

Now, here's one way you can take a base SQL statement, and conditionally execute that dynamic SQL in each database. I did my best to avoid single quotes but sometimes that actually makes things *less* readable.

```
DECLARE @base   nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT DB_NAME(),
                                  CONCAT($schn$, char(46), $tbn$), 
                                  $coln$, MIN($col$) FROM $sch$.$tb$;',
    @nested nvarchar(max) = N'DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = SPACE(0);
SELECT @sql += REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@base, 
  N''$sch$'', QUOTENAME(s.name)), N''$schn$'', QUOTENAME(s.name, char(39))), 
  N''$tb$'',  QUOTENAME(t.name)), N''$tbn$'',  QUOTENAME(t.name, char(39))), 
  N''$col$'', QUOTENAME(c.name)), N''$coln$'', QUOTENAME(c.name, char(39)))
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.types 
  WHERE system_type_id IN (40,41,42,43,61) 
  AND user_type_id = c.user_type_id);
INSERT #AllInfo EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;';

DECLARE @context nvarchar(2000), @c cursor;

SET @c = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR 
         SELECT QUOTENAME(name) + N'.sys.sp_executesql'
         FROM sys.databases WHERE state = 0 AND database_id > 4;

OPEN @c; FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @context;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN
  EXEC @context @nested, N'@base nvarchar(max)', @base;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @c INTO @context;
END
```

Basically, we need to prepare a statement that can be run *in each database* and then, inside each database, *for each column that matches our criteria*. So we have nested dynamic SQL that gets custom-built inside the database cursor, replacing tokens like `$sch$` with the actual schema name, `$tb$` with the actual table name, and `$col$` with the actual column name. The `REPLACE()` is messy, and I initially went that route because I was referencing each token more than once, but it got more complicated because in some places it needed to be rendered as a string literal instead of a bracketed entity name.

Finally:

```
SELECT * FROM #AllInfo;
```

As an aside, please stay away from `sp_MSforeachdb`. This procedure is undocumented and unsupported for a reason: it is *buggy* and skips databases without any warning. It also forces you to reference the database with `?` which can be tedious and even problematic. I wrote a replacement [here](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql), which avoids the bug, and also prevents you from littering your dynamic SQL commands with `?`. You can read more about it in the following posts (and not even all are mine):

- [Use sp_ineachdb Instead of sp_MSforeachdb](https://callihandata.com/2022/09/03/use-sp_ineachdb-instead-of-sp_msforeachdb/)
- [A reliable and flexible replacement for sp_MSforeachdb](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database using sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [T-SQL Tuesday #155 – Do X to all the databases](https://sqlblog.org/2022/10/11/t-sql-tuesday-155-do-x-to-all-the-dbs)

Comment: Hello @Aaron Bertrand, Many Thanks and I really appreciate the time you spent on writing the code & explaining it in detail along with references. I'm still trying to wrap my head around it & understand it better [partly due to my own inexperience :) ]. In the meantime, I did execute the code in my environment & it is somehow limiting the results that are fetched, as in when I execute the original script for 1 database, It gives me over 100 Col with the min_date. However your above script is only fetching 43 records for all databases together. Is there any filter in there limiting the results?

Comment: @VineethNair I spotted the issue, try the updated query.

Comment: After comparing the results, it looks like the script is giving 1 row of output per database. So originally if my database has over 100 cols (across multiple tables) that match the criteria, instead of putting out 100 x No. of DBs (43 in this case). It just gives me 43 rows of output. The cols also seems to be randomly chosen for each DB.

Comment: Sorry I missed your edit to the query. It works fine now. Thank you again :)